# How does one dismiss a pet?

Tags: path-of-exile

How does one dismiss a pet so that another character can use it?

Answer (score 3):

You can dismiss a pet by opening the microtransactions menu and right-clicking the pet with the character that is using the pet.
*You can confirm that this has happened when your pet disappears. You may need to look closely at your character.*

Alternatively, you can add them to your camp by opening the microtransactions menu in camp edit mode, and reclaim them by deleting your pet (as a camp object).
*Note that pets dismissed from the inventory this way cannot be used while the character is out in the fields/dungeons until reclaimed back to the inventory.*